# redirecting output in powershell produces UTF-16 encoded text

Tags: windows-8.1, powershell

If I do `echo zzz > test.txt` and then open test.txt what I see is this:

```
ÿþz z z
```

But sometimes it's just desirable to be able to output single byte encodings. Like maybe the program is outputing a binary file, like a JPEG image, or some such.

Anyway, is there anyway to make it so redirected output in Powershell is done using a single byte encoding instead of a multibyte one?

Comment: The string, "ÿþz z z", is in UTF-16. You can tell from the [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Also, you can see that that "z" characters have an extra character between them, which suggests that the encoding is 2-byte.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following will write the string out in the current Windows ANSI code page. This is probably what you will usually want to do to output single-byte encoded strings.

```
echo zzz | Out-File -Encoding default test.txt
```

You could also use ASCII:

```
echo zzz | Out-File -Encoding ascii test.txt
```

To output a byte array, do something like this:

```
$myByteArray = New-Object Byte[] 100   # Array of 100 bytes.
[io.file]::WriteAllBytes('Test.dat', $myByteArray)
```